# Failure to apply turbofish notation on (boxed) trait objects

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I can create a `Write` trait object that points to a (heap-stored) `File` object as such:

```
let a : Box<dyn Write> = Box::new(File::open("/dev/null").unwrap());  // Compiles fine.
```

Using the turbofish notation, however, produces an error (Rust 1.56.1):

```
let a : Box<dyn Write> = Box::<dyn Write>::new(File::open("/dev/null").unwrap());  // Fails to compile.
```

The error being:

```
error[E0599]: the function or associated item `new` exists for struct `Box<dyn std::io::Write>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
    --> src/main.rs:37:48
     |
37   |     let a : Box<dyn Write> = Box::<dyn Write>::new(File::open("/dev/null").unwrap());  // Fails to compile.
     |                                                ^^^ function or associated item cannot be called on `Box<dyn std::io::Write>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
     |
    ::: /home/[REDACTED]/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/std/src/io/mod.rs:1368:1
     |
1368 | pub trait Write {
     | --------------- doesn't satisfy `dyn std::io::Write: Sized`
     |
     = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
             `dyn std::io::Write: Sized`
```

I've been poking at the problem for the better part of a day. Either I'm missing something fundamental, or the [special language treatment of Box](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/special-types-and-traits.html#boxt) is at play here (but I don't see how).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is actually quite deceptive.

```rust
let a: Box<dyn Write> = Box::new(File::open("/dev/null").unwrap());
```

doesn't actually create a `Box<dyn Write>` like you think. It first creates a `Box<File>`, then the `Box<File>` is cast into a `Box<dyn Write>`. If you turbofish with `File`, then it works:

```rust
let a: Box<dyn Write> = Box::<File>::new(File::open("/dev/null").unwrap());
```

So, if you want to be explicit about the type, use an `as` cast instead of turbofish:

```rust
// a is Box<dyn Write>
let a = Box::new(File::open("/dev/null").unwrap()) as Box<dyn Write>;
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. I've re-read the relevant paragraph in "Programming Rust" and indeed, it explicitly mentions the conversion: "Likewise, Rust will happily convert a Box<File> to a Box<dyn Write> , a value that owns a writer in the heap."

I'll do some tests with this in mind; meanwhile, solid +1.